# Merge 2 xml files using XSLT in unix

Tags: xml, unix, xslt, merge

I have 2 XML files as shown below:

**File1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Schedule name="myOffice">
  <taskItem taskId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>USD</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="28" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
  <taskItem taskId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>Rupee</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="15" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
</Schedule>
```

**File2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Schedule name="myOffice">
  <taskItem taskId="1" startDate="2015-12-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>Rupee</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="5" duration="10" hour="0" interval="20" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
</Schedule>
```

I am using XSLT to get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Schedule name="myOffice">
  <taskItem taskId="1" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>USD</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="0" duration="0" hour="0" interval="28" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
  <taskItem taskId="2" startDate="2013-01-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>Rupee</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="5" duration="10" hour="0" interval="20" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
</Schedule>
```

But getting this as output:

```
<Schedule name="myOffice">
  <taskItem taskId="1" startDate="2015-12-01" stopDate="2037-12-31">
    <measurements>
      <measurement>Rupee</measurement>
    </measurements>
    <timings>
      <period day="5" duration="10" hour="0" interval="20" minutes="0"/>
    </timings>
  </taskItem>
</Schedule>
```

I am not able to get where I am lagging....

My idea is, based on field `Measurement`, I have to update attributes `stopDate` in `taskItem`, and `day`,`duration`,`hour`,`interval`,`minutes` in `period` tag.

My XSLT file is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="taskItem//measurement">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="document('file1.xml')
              /Schedule/taskItem/timings/period[@day = current()/../../timings/period/@day and
                                                @duration = current()/../../timings/period/@duration and 
                                                @hour = current()/../../timings/period/@hour and
                                                @interval = current()/../../timings/period/@interval and
                                                @minutes = current()/../../timings/period/@minutes]/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am executing the command in unix as follows:

```
xsltproc xs.xslt file2.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="timings">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="document('file2.xml')/Schedule/taskItem[measurements/measurement=current()/../measurements/measurement]/timings"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$match"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and specify `file1.xml` as the file to be processed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the output which I got was not having header....how can I include ....this one directly by XSLT....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

Comment: I thought you didn't want the XML declaration, because your XSLT explicitly omits it and I copied that. If you do want it, remove the `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` attribute from the `xsl:output` instruction (or change its value to `"yes"`).

Comment: this one is adding only `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, but if I want complete header, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`, then what should I do

Comment: Make your `xsl:output` instruction `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my (verbose) solution from what I understood. I explicitly update each attributes/fields so you can tweak this solution to adapt it to your needs. The taskId and startDate from the taskItem are taken from file1.xml. The stopDate and timings are take from file2.xml. You must call this XSLT sheet with file1.xml as parameter.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- For all taskItem in file1.xml -->
  <xsl:template match="taskItem">
    <!-- Get all taskItems from file2.xml -->
    <xsl:variable name="tiother" select="document('file2.xml')/Schedule/taskItem" />
    <!-- Get measurement text from current and other taskItems (from file1.xml and file2.xml) -->
    <xsl:variable name="namethis" select="./measurements/measurement/text()" />
    <xsl:variable name="nameother" select="$tiother/measurements/measurement/text()" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if the measurement texts are the same -->
      <xsl:when test="$namethis = $nameother">
        <!-- Yes ? create a new taskItem updated -->
        <xsl:element name="taskItem">
          <!-- Get taskId from the current task item (the one in file1.xml) -->
          <xsl:attribute name="taskId"><xsl:value-of select="./@taskId"/></xsl:attribute>
          <!-- Get startDate from the current task item (the one in file1.xml) -->
          <xsl:attribute name="startDate"><xsl:value-of select="./@startDate"/></xsl:attribute>
          <!-- Get stopDate from the other task item (the one in file2.xml) -->
          <xsl:attribute name="stopDate"><xsl:value-of select="$tiother/@stopDate"/></xsl:attribute>
          <!-- Get the measurements from the current task item (the one in file1.xml) -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="./measurements"/>
          <!-- Get the timings from the other task item (the one in file2.xml) -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="$tiother/timings"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- No ? just copy the current taskItem -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```